# Помогите отредактировать задание по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, условия

Вот задание
Дан текстовый файл с именем c.txt, в файле записаны N целых чисел, по одному
в строке. Определить количество цифр в самом "длинном" числе. Обязательно использовать
логическую переменную и НЕ использовать оператор ветвления в теле цикла. Списки использовать запрещается, а файл для чтения открывать только один раз.

Программа работает, но по условию запрещено использовать операторы ветвления в цикле или же как у меня в функции. Как можно найти максимум не используя if. По прошлому заданию(вопрос удалили, но там нужно было просто все строки в файле проверить на одно условие) мне дали подсказку использовать flag = True, flag = flag and (n > 0), в том случае это было уместно тк выводиться должно было True/False, а вот с этим заданием разобраться не могу.

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

maximum = 0


def my_max(n):
    global maximum
    if n > maximum:
        maximum = n
        return n
    else:
        raise ValueError


with (open("c.txt", "r") as f):  # используем менеджер контекста для открытия файла, он же его и закроет
    flag = True  # добавляем переменную которая всегда True
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):  # с помощью enumerate() перебираем строки и их индексы
        try:
            max_line = my_max(len(str(int(line))))
        except ValueError:
            continue
print(max_line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max_line = 0

with (open("c.txt", "r") as f):  # используем менеджер контекста для открытия файла, он же его и закроет
    flag = True  # добавляем переменную которая всегда True
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):  # с помощью enumerate() перебираем строки и их индексы
        try:
            current_line = len(str(abs(int(line))))
            max_line = max(current_line, max_line)
        except ValueError:
            continue
print(max_line)
```

Comment: 1) непонятно, зачем вам `enumerate`, вы `i` нигде не используете. 2) `"r"` - режим открытия файла по умолчанию, можно его не писать. 3) исключения нельзя просто игнорировать, нужно хотя бы печатать, что произошла ошибка, а так вы никогда не узнаете, что есть проблема; если проблема реально есть, её нужно решать, а не игнорировать

Answer (score 0):

```
def longest_number():
    with (open("c.txt", "r") as f):
        lines = f.read()
        return sorted(lines.split('\n'), key=len, reverse=True)[0]
```

В этом коде мы используем встроенную функцию Python `sorted()`, с помощью которой производим сортировку строк файла по длине, а затем возвращаем первую из этих строк.

Comment: нужно определить именно количество цифр в самом длинном числе, и если использовать len(), то в случае когда число отрицательное, он минус также считает, а нужно только цифры

Comment: Сортировать не нужно, max тоже принимает ключ сравнения или лямбду

Comment: @A1cogolik Такого уточнения в вопросе не было, но вы можете сделать функцию сравнения с  len(abs())

Comment: "...в файле записаны N целых чисел...", насколько я знаю целые числа бывают и отрицательные

Comment: @A1cogolik `он минус также считает, а нужно только цифры`  - это неоднозначно.